# Change navbar dropdownlist button to red after clicking on it

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I need to figure out a way to style the drop down list button to turn red after I focus by clicking on it. Whether this is accomplished in the bootstrap or by JavaScript I really need to know. The main issue is that every time I click on the drop down list button on the navbar it defaults to black and I've tried to change it in the bootstrap, JavaScript, and other means, but I've honestly had no luck.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/Default.aspx" style="text-align: left; width: 94px; margin-right: 70px;">
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/icons/FCOTICON.png" Height="55px" Width="110px" /></a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/Resources/aspx">Resources</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown" style="background-color:red;">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle, navText" data-toggle="dropdown"  role="button" aria-expanded="true" style="color: #2A4B7B;">Apps<span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
                         <li><a href="">Cisco Wireless</a></li>
                         <li class="divider"></li>
                         <li><a href="">DMS</a></li>
                         <li class="divider"></li>
                     </ul>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Here are two images which will better explain my issue.

The first image is before I click on it and my mouse is only hovered over the button. I don't just want the button to be red, but only after focusing on it by clicking on it.

[image: Before Click]

This second image is after I click on it when the color defaults to black.

[image: After Click]

Comment: Simple JS could solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is overriding your style.

In your site.css, put:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Make sure the site.css file comes after bootstrap.css file in your _Layout.cshtml file.